# Video.js change Focus style

Tags: css, vue.js, electron, video.js

I'm using Video.js together with Vue.js and Electron.js and I'm trying to change the outline of the video player to something a bit better looking than the standard yellow outline but the outline just stays as it is.
My Video Component:

```
<template>
  <div id="video-container">
    <video class="video-js" id="video-player" ref="video"></video>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import videojs from "video.js";

export default {
  name: "Preferences",
  props: ["item"],
  methods: {
    getPath: function () {
      return this.item.dir + "/" + this.item.name + "." + this.item.fileType;
    },
  },
  mounted: function () {
    let options = {
      autoplay: false,
      controls: true,
      fluid: true,
      playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2],
      controlBar: {
        pictureInPictureToggle: false,
      },
    };
    this.player = videojs(this.$refs.video, options).src(this.getPath());
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#video-player {
  outline: none;
}
</style>
```

I've also tried `!important`, `#video-player:hover` and using the video-container div to change the outline but so far nothing worked.
The outline looks like this:
[Video Box outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgIzR.png)
[button outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZebe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying, you are talking about the bowser focus, that blue line around the focus component.

you need something like

```
.video-js:focus {
   outline-style: none;
}
```

if still not working you can add `!important` or add this too

```
.video-js:focus {
   outline-style: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border-color: transparent;
}
```

Normally we don't remove this for the simple reason that could be hard to use Tab around the components. But if you are ok with that go for it!

**EDIT (10/02/2021):**

So for the video JS, you can actually use your custom class and overwrite the Video-js CSS class in order to do that you will need to create this 3 follow classes in your CSS.

```
.vjs-matrix.video-js {
  color: #00ff00;
/*put other stuff you need here*/
}

/* Change the border of the big play button. */
.vjs-matrix .vjs-big-play-button {
  border-color: #00ff00;
/*put other stuff you need here*/
}

/* Change the color of various "bars". */
.vjs-matrix .vjs-volume-level,
.vjs-matrix .vjs-play-progress,
.vjs-matrix .vjs-slider-bar {
  background: #00ff00;
/*put other stuff you need here*/
}
```

**And for your HTML**

```
<video class="vjs-matrix video-js">...</video>
```

Try to play around with this and see if fix your problem!

Source ([videojs](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-skins.html))

Comment: I've tried this but it still doesn't work, tho i agree that it should. Maybe there is an error somewhere else in my code that i haven't found yet. I updated my question with pictures of my problem.

Comment: Probably is an inside CSS class for tag video. Most likely your Video-js is loaded first then other classes overwrite it! From what I see in the images that should be the case! I Will edit my answer with the changes for those classes!

Comment: Thanks alot, i was finally able to fix the issue by adding another css class in another file and importing it under the video-js css file, There i can just change all classes from the video-js css file i want to change, thanks alot for the link! If i ever get 15 points I'll upvote your answer :D

Comment: Cool. Sometimes we just need a push to find the fix!